# Stretchable gui in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to create a GUI in C++/Qt that will stretch seamless across the screen? I don't refer to a rearrangement of the GUI elements (buttons/text etc..), I mean a complete change in the aspect ratio of the GUI as it were a plain image.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499062/scalable-painting-of-a-qt-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt used size policies [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsizepolicy.html) to define how the GUIs resize. Set the elements to QSizePolicy::Expanding that should consume the extra space.

Comment: does it'll consume the extra space leaving it empty?