# Qt: transform widget by QGraphicsScene possible?

Tags: qt, widget, transformation

I want to transform (scale, rote) QWidget objects (e.g. buttons). Based on this discussion:
[Scalable painting of a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499062/scalable-painting-of-a-qt-application)
I have the following in the constructor of my main window. CMyGraphicsView is derived from QGraphicsView without changes until now.

The text is transformed, but not the button. Is this the right way to achieve this? Is this possible at all with build in tools?

```
CMyGraphicsView *view = new CMyGraphicsView(this);

view->setGeometry(0, 0, geometry().width(), geometry().height());
view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy ( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
view->win = this;

this->setCentralWidget(view);  

QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, geometry().width(), geometry().height(), this);
scene->addText("Hello, world!");
view->setScene(scene);


QToolButton *btn = new QToolButton(this);
btn->move(10,20);
btn->setStyleSheet("background-color: gray");
btn->setStyleSheet("QToolButton:pressed{background-color: red}");
btn->setStyleSheet("QToolButton:checked{background-color: red}");

scene->addWidget(btn);

view->scale(1.5,0.7);
view->rotate(9);
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Lg2djhm.png)

Comment: Puh, that's weird. I had to change the constructor of the button to 'new QToolButton(NULL)', there is also a warning message generated which I may overlooked last night saying the button could not be embedded ...
Nevertheless, now it works! Thanks for the support!

Comment: It worked for me because I omitted `this` (because I wrote it in the `main` function). You may post an answer yourself to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

as in the comments above:

```
QToolButton *btn = new QToolButton(this);
```

has to be chanched to

```
QToolButton *btn = new QToolButton(NULL);
```

than it works fine.